How to use material 3 (1.2.1) and asFlow?
I made some changes to Skizo-ozᴉʞS ツ variant and now it works fine:
private val eventsChannel = MutableSharedFlow<Event>(
    replay = 1, extraBufferCapacity = 64,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST

)

and sendEvent function:
fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
    eventBusScope.launch {
        eventsChannel.emit(event)
    }
}

I need to upgrade material 3 from 1.1.2 to 1.2.1, but if I do so, I get error concerning asFlow() -
Using 'asFlow(): Flow<T>' is an error. 'BroadcastChannel' is obsolete and all corresponding operators are deprecated in the favour of StateFlow and SharedFlow

Is there any possibility to use material 3 1.2.1 and asFlow together?
I tried upgrading but I get compilation error.
The code as follows:
object EventBus {
@OptIn(ObsoleteCoroutinesApi::class)
private val eventsChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Event>()
private val screenState = MutableStateFlow(ContentType.EMPTY)
private val screenOperatorState = MutableStateFlow(OperatorContentType.EMPTY)

@OptIn(ObsoleteCoroutinesApi::class)
val eventFlow: Flow<Event>
    get() = eventsChannel.asFlow()

val getScreen: Flow<ContentType>
    get() = screenState

val getOperatorScreen: Flow<OperatorContentType>
    get() = screenOperatorState

@OptIn(ObsoleteCoroutinesApi::class)
fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
    Log.d("MyLogBackArrow","sendEvent in EventBus $event")
    eventsChannel.trySend(event).isSuccess
}

fun <C>setScreen(screenType: C) {
    when(screenType){
        is ContentType -> {
            screenState.value = screenType

        }

        is OperatorContentType -> {
            screenOperatorState.value = screenType
        }
    }
}

}

Can you share the code you have in place? Also, why not migrate asFlow to StateFlow/SharedFlow depending on your use case.

I added the code. I tried to migrate but the app does not work properly, so I don't know how to fix it.

You should change the code so you use :

asSharedFlow()


Represents this mutable shared flow as a read-only shared flow.
public fun  MutableSharedFlow.asSharedFlow(): SharedFlow =
ReadonlySharedFlow(this, null)


tryEmitin case you don't have any CoroutineScopebut without the isSuccess

object EventBus {

    private val eventsChannel = MutableSharedFlow<Event>()
    private val screenState = MutableStateFlow(ContentType.EMPTY)
    private val screenOperatorState = MutableStateFlow(OperatorContentType.EMPTY)

    val eventFlow: Flow<Event>
        get() = eventsChannel.asSharedFlow()

    val getScreen: Flow<ContentType>
        get() = screenState

    val getOperatorScreen: Flow<OperatorContentType>
        get() = screenOperatorState

    fun sendEvent(event: Event) {
        Log.d("MyLogBackArrow","sendEvent in EventBus $event")
        eventsChannel.tryEmit(event)
    }

    fun <C> setScreen(screenType: C) {
        when (screenType) {
            is ContentType -> {
                screenState.value = screenType
            }
            is OperatorContentType -> {
                screenOperatorState.value = screenType
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried it, but there is some issue with updating states. I think the problem in sendEvent and isSuccess
